# Javascript OOP variables from class

Tags: javascript

Ey everyone, I am trying to make a javascript class and get its data off the class. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
    var App = {

    data: {
        string = "String"
    }

    login: function() {
        return alert(data.string);  
    }
}

var me = App.login();
```

Well, what I am trying to accomplish is getting the string value off data and alert it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.In Object literal you must use `:` instead of `=`.

2.to get property in object use `this` (`this.data.string`)

3.add `,` after `data: {}`

```
var App = {

    data: {
        string: "String"
    },

    login: function() {
        return alert(this.data.string);  
    }
};

var me = App.login();
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/sucago/1/edit?js,console)